# Are all those permissions needed by PhoneGap on Android?

Tags: android, cordova

Looking at phonegap documentation for hello world and there are a bunch of permissions. About 15 in the Android manifest. Just wondering if all of them are required?

See http://phonegap.com/start/#android

Answer (score 7):

I've figured out, based on the answer by ghostCoder, that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Is the only permission which is needed for a minimal phonegap App to start and run if you don't access the internet or any other special resources.

Comment: I'm interested how you have a webview working without internet permission...weird how it worked for me, but this confirms what you say: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10401522/805031 something must have changed...

Comment: correct... I wonder if something changed in Android's requirements for webview implementation... It seems only `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` is all that is needed now.

Comment: Well, I don't need permission to access the INTERNET because my web app runs entirely locally. I want it to be usable offline. So I wonder why I need any permissions because it doesn't access anything outside at all.

Comment: Because phonegap is a webview, I'm assuming. **It is strange**, though. Even only accessing local HTML etc. they, for some reason, require that setting...most likely to communicate with its own webview implementation.

Comment: Yes this one solved my Issue "Unfortunately <myapp> has been stopped"

Answer (score 5):

For PhoneGap, since it is mostly a glorified WebView implementation, you are required to have at the very minimum:

```
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE 
android.permission.INTERNET
```

in your Manifest.xml

If you need any other permissions, that will depend on your specific application and what it needs to do.

Hope that helps!

Referenced: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/Mrrvk0Q0KqA and others.

Comment: READ_PHONE_STATE and INTERNET doesn't seam to be enough. My App crashes if I set only these both permissions.

Comment: @white_gecko for a hello_world demo app? Are you sure your app isn't using something else? It works for me, so that's strange.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the Manifest, and what the HelloWorld application does on PhoneGap,All the permissions do not appear to be needed.

They seem to be there to show you what is available. I dont believe the single hello world app uses ALL those permissions.

Answer (score 4):

The only permissions you would need are-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

once you add features like camera and all, you can add more permissions.

Comment: What makes you think you need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` ?

Answer (score 4):

You only need to add one line to config.xml:

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
```

- Of course if you require more permissions then add them accordingly. But this will at least remove all those unnecessary default perms...

More info: http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/

Comment: Didn't work for me, the app still asks for mic, photos, location etc. on install

Comment: Make sure you remove all the default "plugins" as well, they require a ton of permissions

Answer (score 2):

I think that is just for the example project, depending what you plan on using on you can set the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its necessary to explicitly state which permissions you don't want, although this shouldn't really be the case.

On a more general note, I always use this great little tool to build my config.xml files for phonegap. It's got pretty much every base covered and prompts you for all the relevant/useful data, even giving the sizes of icons and splashscreens for every device type.

I'd seriously recommend every phonegap developer downloads and uses this:
http://configap.com/

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, PhoneGap 2.4.0 allows us to remove the `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`.

Or generally, every permission as you don't need in your app can be removed, and you have to remove the corresponding plugin in `res/xml/config.xml`.

I am using the Android version, and when I removed plugin which requires network access, I could remove the `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission.

However, I couldn't use Eclipse GUI to add those plugins back once removed. I needed to edit the XML file manually. And the original plugin list could be found at `Android Dependencies` > `cordova-2.4.9.jar`

Comment: I tried to remove the INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and I get an error when trying to launch my app on the actual device...  So I added those permissions back in and all is well.  I'm using Icenium which is awesome :-)  http://www.icenium.com/

Comment: As I said, you need to remove the corresponding plugin in res/xml/config.xml as well. Did you do that?