# Hello World phonegap app crashing

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

Alright, I am trying to just get the demo working on their website, but when I try to install it and run on my phone, I get this exception in Eclipse:

`05-01 13:10:49.637: E/AndroidRuntime(19669): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10128 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.`

I thought maybe it was because it was on WiFi, but it persisted after I disabled that as well.  Does anyone know what is causing this?  I am literally doing the bare minimum.  This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <title>PhoneGap</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0rc1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need permissions to access network, update their config/manifest file to include this - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>`

Comment: Yup, I just stumbled upon that immediately after I posted the question lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, like 3 seconds after I posted this.

Basically, you have to add a line to the androidmanifest.xml file to the permissions.  In eclipse, you just need to add this:

`android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`

and that did the trick!

---

Since apparently this is not clear, THIS IS FOR ECLIPSE.  Eclipse has a nice editor which will allow you to add properties via a dropdown menu.  You can still go in and manually add entries into the manifest file.  This is much simpler though.

Comment: Your instructions on how to fix are incomplete seeing as you need to add the full  permissions use xml tag to the Android Manifest not just reference a constant value.  i.e. it should say:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: Reread the response.  I said in eclipse.  Eclipse handles that stuff for you.  So, for this use case, they are indeed complete.

Comment: You didn't specify that you were within the Android ADT plugin for Eclipse permissions panel of the Manifest. Eclipse doesn't handle that stuff for you.  Android ADT plugin for Eclipse handles it for you, and only if you use the guided style editing for permissions for the Android Manifest.  If you are editing the AndroidManifest.xml file in eclipse then you need to add the full statement.  Since you did not say you used ADT guided permissions pane, your answer is still incomplete.  Generally, if you don't fully understand how something works, don't jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that you haven't completed one of the steps in their guides correctly.  That being setting up your AndroidManifest.xml file to properly reflect the permissions that phonegap requires/activities it will use on each android device.

Try re-reading what it says at: 
http://phonegap.com/start#android

**Specifically under step #3 when the instructions say:**
Right click on AndroidManifest.xml and select Open With > Text Editor
Paste the following permissions under versionName: (view image below)

and make absolutely certain your AndroidManifext.xml in the Eclipse hello world project has all of that in it exactly as it tells you to paste it.

Comment: Yeah, must've missed that one...