# Can a Phonegap app run with out NETWORK permission

Tags: android, cordova

I had develop an app which is not using any Internet settings and not accessing network state in phonegap version 1.7 but the app is not running with our using below permission
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` 
in the manifest

Comment: Also use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697295/are-all-those-permissions-needed-by-phonegap-on-android. It is answered with good detail

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if you have tried searching you might got your answer a bit earlier than this 
[Are all those permissions needed by PhoneGap on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697295/are-all-those-permissions-needed-by-phonegap-on-android)